# How to reverse filter based on latest entry in Django

Tags: django, foreign-keys, django-filter

I have a customer table and customer order table as below

```
class Customer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class CustomerOder(models.Model):
  customer = models.ForiengKey(Customer)
  item = models.CharField()
  datetime_of_purchase = models.DateField()
```

Sample database entry

Table: Customer

```
id    name
1     A
2     B
3     C
```

Table: CustomerOrder

```
id   customer   item     datetime_of_purchase
1    A          item_3   2021-11-10 10:00:00
2    A          item_2   2021-11-11 10:00:00
3    B          item_1   2021-11-11 10:00:00
4    A          item_1   2021-11-12 10:00:00
5    B          item_2   2021-11-12 10:00:00
6    C          item_1   2021-11-13 10:00:00
```

Suppose i need to filter customer whose latest purchase is 'items_1' so the sample after filtering  should get only Customer 'A' and 'C' whose latest purchase is 'item_1'

```
Sample:
<QuerySet [<Customer: A>, <Customer: C>]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the latest pruchased item with a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Customer.objects.alias(
    latest_purchase=Subquery(
        CustomerOrder.objects.filter(
            customer_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-datetime_of_purchase').values('item')[:1]
    )
).filter(latest_purchase='item_1')
```

Prior to [django-3.2](/questions/tagged/django-3.2), one uses [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) over [**`.alias(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#alias):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

Customer.objects.annotate(
    latest_purchase=Subquery(
        CustomerOrder.objects.filter(
            customer_id=OuterRef('pk')
        ).order_by('-datetime_of_purchase').values('item')[:1]
    )
).filter(latest_purchase='item_1')
```